# Google Apps script editor - publish > test as add on... - is this a new feature and how does it work?

Tags: google-apps-script

Today in my google apps script editor I see a new button under 'publish' - I now have the option to 'test as add-on'.  I have tried a number of things that I thought may be different in test mode like calling e.authMode from onOpen, adding an onInstall() function but the test behaves exactly the same as my normal version

I am presuming this is a new feature?  Any documentation and / or tips on this

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Google's way to announce new features are the [Blog](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com.br/) and the [G+ Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769), no word on either, so they are probably experimenting with it and will be announced today or over the weekend. I also tried testing the add-on and no result whatsoever.

Comment: ...still no word, so this feature remains somewhat of a mystery?  Any comments from anyone in the know really appreciated....